# can't seem to commit a file in git

Tags: git

I don't know why, but I can't commit and push this new file I added.

```
$ git st
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   css/clearfix.css
#


$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date

$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: You don't commit in your example - you just `push` and `pull` (neither of them is a `commit`)

Comment: huh? it says a new file has been added. maybe i'm not using the right terminology. How do I push the new file to the git repo?

Comment: It's added to the stage, not committed yet. Commit is performed with `git commit`. "Changes **to be** committed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have add the changes to staging area only. You didn't commit it yet. Use `git commit -m "Your Commit Message"` to commit the changes. For further details, refer [here](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/18/the-staging-area.html)

Answer (score 1):

What you see on your screen is a staged file.

Basically it means that git is aware of your changes but they haven't been persisted yet, which should be done using

```
git commit -m "Commit Message"
```

After that you're supposed to perform `git push` if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add your new file to git repository:

```
git add css/clearfix.css
```

Then you need to commit file to your local repository:

```
git commit css/clearfix.css
```

You are now ready to push your changes.